# The expectation of a measurement of qubit 2 after qubit 1 has been measured

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, textbook-and-exercises

In section 1.2.4 (page 13) of these lecture notes [http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~vidick/teaching/fsmp/fsmp.pdf](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/%7Evidick/teaching/fsmp/fsmp.pdf), it says

\begin{aligned}\left\langle\psi\left|X_{1}^{0} Z_{2} X_{1}^{0}\right| \psi\right\rangle+\left\langle\psi\left|X_{1}^{1} Z_{2} X_{1}^{1}\right| \psi\right\rangle &=\left\langle\psi\left|X_{1} Z_{2} X_{1}\right| \psi\right\rangle \\ &=\left\langle\psi\left|Z_{2} X_{1}^{2}\right| \psi\right\rangle \\ &=\left\langle\psi\left|Z_{2}\right| \psi\right\rangle \end{aligned}

given that $X_{1}=X_{1}^{0}-X_{1}^{1}$ where this is the spectral decomposition, but I don't see how this can be. How did the negative terms cancel out?

Comment: Can you point to the section of the paper where this is shown?

Comment: Hi again @epelaaez, it is in section 1.2.4 on page 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would do the calculation a little differently. Start by writing
$$
\langle\psi|X^0_1Z_2X^0_1|\psi\rangle+
\langle\psi|X^1_1Z_2X^1_1|\psi\rangle=
\langle\psi|X^0_1Z_2X^0_1+X^1_1Z_2X^1_1|\psi\rangle
$$
Next, think about a term like $X^0_1Z_2X^0_1$, but expand out the tensor product. This is just $(X^0X^0)\otimes Z$. But since $X^0$ is a projector, it's just $X^0$. So, our full expression looks like
$$
\langle\psi|X^0\otimes Z+X^1\otimes Z_2|\psi\rangle=\langle\psi|(X^0+X^1)\otimes Z|\psi\rangle
$$
Now, $X^0+X^1=I$, because it's a sum over an orthonormal basis. Hence, this is just $\langle\psi|Z_2|\psi\rangle$.

Note that I never introduced any negative terms that needed cancelling out.